# Excel VBA macro to copy specific rows and delete it

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

Here what I want to do:

- I have 2 worksheet named Pending & Records.
- Columns in "Pending" worksheet: A: Date, B: Delivery To, C: Delivery to office, D: Delivery to Manager, E: Subject, F: Date & G: Letter No.
- Columns in "Records" worksheet: A: Date, B: Letter No. & C: Subject.
- When entered number in cell G (Letter No.) of "Pending" worksheet, the below cells copy to specified cells in "Records" worksheet.
- E (Subject) in "Pending" worksheet sit in C (subject) of "Records" worksheet.
- F (Date) in "Pending" worksheet sit in A (Date) of "Records" worksheet.
- G (Letter No.) in "Pending" worksheet sit in B (Letter No.) of "Records" worksheet.
- Delete the row that was copied in "Pending" worksheet.
- Sort the rows in "Records" worksheet according to Letter No. (Column C).

This is codes that I write for what I want to do (not work good) and some screenshot:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Target.Column = 6 Then
    If Len(Target.Value) > 0 Then
        Dim r As Range
        Dim a As String
        Dim b As String

        b = "sheet3!A" & Sheet1.Cells(1, 9) + 3 & ":C" & Sheet1.Cells(1, 9) + 3
        a = "E" & Target.Row & ":G" & Target.Row
        Dim r1, r2 As Range
        r1 = Sheet1.Range(a)
        Sheet2.Range(b).Value = r1
        Sheet1.Range(a).EntireRow.Delete
    End If
End If

End Sub
```

[picture 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t7xTm.jpg)
[picture 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sQim3.jpg)

Comment: According to your post you want to run this code when a value in column "G" is changed, but in your code you are lookng for `Target.Column = 6` - which is Column "F", not Column "G"

Comment: it work thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the code below in "Pending" worksheet module, under `Worksheet_Change` event.

First, you should learn to enjoy the benefits of the `Target` variable.

For instance, if you want to copy a value from column "F" at the same row of Column "G" (your `Target`), you can use `Target.Offset(, -1).Copy`.

If you want to delete the entire row of your `Target` after it's copied, simply use `Target.EntireRow.Delete`.

Another thing, according to your screen-shot (and the first part of your post) "Letter No" is located at Column "B" in "Records" sheet. Therefore, the `Sort` is done according to Column "B".

**Code**

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As range)

Dim RecSht      As Worksheet
Dim NextRow     As Long

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = False

If Target.Column = 7 Then ' Column "G"
    If Target.Value <> "" Then
        Set RecSht = Worksheets("Records")
        NextRow = RecSht.Cells(RecSht.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1 ' <-- get next empty row at Column A in "Records" sheet

        RecSht.Range("B" & NextRow).Value = Target.Value ' column "G"
        RecSht.Range("A" & NextRow).Value = Target.Offset(, -1).Value ' column "F"
        RecSht.Range("C" & NextRow).Value = Target.Offset(, -2).Value ' column "E"

        Target.EntireRow.Delete ' <-- Delete entire row that was copied

        '--- Sort Section ---
        RecSht.Range("A2:C" & NextRow).Sort key1:=RecSht.Range("B2:B" & NextRow), _
                                         order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes
    End If
End If

Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```